# Error: FATAL_ERROR | System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries across namespaces: 1101

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am hitting this error in a Unit Test on an org where I am converting multiple leads in bulk. The same Unit Test passes correctly if I only convert 1 Lead. But when I try to convert 50 at once, the test method does not pass and in the debug logs I found this error:

```
FATAL_ERROR | System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries across namespaces: 1101
```

I have googled and searched but either noone has posted about this issue or my googlefu skills are lacking. I did find a lot of hits of a similar error of just hitting the limit, but this "across namespaces: 1101" is what's making me think this is another case.

If anyone has a clue what it could be or where I could look at, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

There's a limit to how many queries can be run in total across all installed packages. It sounds like you may have a few packages that are less than efficient with queries. This probably won't be an issue in practice, since it's rare to see more than one lead conversion per transaction. That said, if you turn on profiling for your tests, you can determine which package is causing the problem and work with the specific vendor to try and resolve it.

Comment: This is interesting - I didn't actually know there was an overall limit across namespaces. For reference, I found a "Cumulative Cross-Namespace Limit" table in the [Apex Governor Limits documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm)

Comment: Also, more specifically, the limit is 11 times the per-namespace limit: "There’s also a limit on the cumulative number of operations that can be made across namespaces in a transaction. This cumulative limit is 11 times the per-namespace limit. For example, if the per-namespace limit for SOQL queries is 100, a single transaction can perform up to 1,100 SOQL queries."

Comment: Thanks for the information sfdcfox and Robert Watson. However, there is only 1 package in this org and it's Rollup Helper, which is not causing any trouble in this specific scenario. What I did notice from profiling however, is that the Lead Trigger that is doing the Lead Convert operation, is being run 104 times when the test is run with 50 Leads. For some reason, it does not seem to be treating the operation in bulk, meaning we are doing 1 Lead Insert operation and 1 Lead Convert operation, but it seems to do a single transaction for each Lead. If that makes any sense.